# Problem with plotting the derivative of a ParametricFunction

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs, parametric-functions

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and continuing through 11.3; Reported as CASE:3691952**

I am trying to calculate and plot the sensitivity of a solution to some master equation using `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`, but I'm unable to plot the derivative of the solution with respect to the parameter.

```
y[t_] = {y11[t], y12[t], y13[t], y21[t], y22[t], y23[t], y31[t], y32[t], y33[t]};
equations = 
  Table[(y'[t] - S1.y[t])[[j]] == 0, {j, 1, 9}] /. {Ω -> Γ3, Γ -> 1};
startConditions = 
  {y11[0] == 1/3, y12[0] == 0, y13[0] == 0, 
   y21[0] == 0, y22[0] == 1/3, y23[0] == 0, 
   y31[0] == 0, y32[0] == 0, y33[0] == 1/3};
system = Join[equations, startConditions];
solution = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[system, y33[1], {t, 0, 1}, {δ, Γ3}, 
   MaxSteps -> ∞];
Plot[Evaluate[D[solution[δ, 1], δ]], {δ, -1, 1}]
```

where `S1` is a $9\times9$ matrix whose elements contain the parameters `δ, Ω  Γ3, Γ`:

```
S1 = {{0, 0, I Ω, 0, 0, 0, -I Ω, 0, Γ},
      {0, -Γ3 + 2 I δ, I Ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I Ω, 0},
      {I Ω, I Ω, -Γ + I δ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I Ω},
      {0, 0, 0, -Γ3 - 2 I δ, 0, I Ω, -I Ω, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, I Ω, 0, -I Ω, Γ},
      {0, 0, 0, I Ω, I Ω, -Γ - I δ, 0, 0, -I Ω},
      {-I Ω, 0, 0, -I Ω, 0, 0, -Γ - I δ, 0, I Ω},
      {0, -I Ω, 0, 0, -I Ω, 0, 0, -Γ + I δ, I Ω},
      {0, 0, -I Ω, 0, 0, -I Ω, I Ω, I Ω, -2 Γ}};
```

The code plots nothing and also doesn't print any error message. The kernel autoquits when I try to plot.  (Edit: Kernel no longer terminates in v11.2.)

Whereas:

```
Plot[Evaluate[solution[δ, 1]], {δ, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say anything if you don't include `S1`.

Comment: You can now find your question under "Problem with plotting the derivative of a ParametricFunction", which is what I isolated as the problem.

Comment: @Feyre, Shahar: It is not plot-related, the problem manifests when you try to calculate: `D[solution[δ, 1], δ] /. δ -> 1`, and the kernel automatically quits.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I see, but `Evaluate[D[solution[\[Delta], 1], \[Delta]]]` runs fine for me, so it's actually extracting values from the Derivative function which causes the auto quit.

Comment: @Feyre: but just try to substitute delta in your code with `Replace`, like I did.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Well, then a solution immediately presents itself :)

Comment: @Feyre Nevertheless, the calculation should terminate gracefully, and not with a kernel quit. It's always an indication of the lack of proper error handling internally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A straightforward but surprising approach is to specify `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` (or most any other value) in `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

```
solution = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, y33[1], {t, 0, 1}, {δ, Γ3}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision];
Plot[Evaluate[D[solution[δ, 1], δ] // Chop], {δ, -1, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {δ, "D[y33[1][δ, 1], δ]"}]
```

[image]

This bizarre behavior certainly must be a bug.

**Earlier workaround**

A workaround is to differentiate the ODE system with respect to `δ` and then solve simultaneously for `y` and `D[y[δ], δ]`.  This is accomplished by adding to the equations in the question the following.

```
dS1 = D[S1, δ];
dy[t_] = {dy11[t], dy12[t], dy13[t], dy21[t], dy22[t], dy23[t], dy31[t], dy32[t], dy33[t]};
dequations = Thread[(dy'[t] - S1.dy[t]) - dS1.y[t] == 0] /. {Ω -> Γ3, Γ -> 1};
dstartConditions = Thread[dy[0] == 0];
dsystem = Join[equations, dequations, startConditions, dstartConditions];
dsolution = ParametricNDSolveValue[dsystem, dy33[1], {t, 0, 1}, {δ, Γ3}];
Plot[dsolution[δ, 1], {δ, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {δ, "D[y33[1][δ, 1], δ]"}]
```

giving the same plot as above.  This approach can be applied to general parametric ODE systems, although the fact that `δ` appears linearly in this ODE system is particularly convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workaround:

Extract the values of the original function:

```
list = Table[{δ, solution[δ, 1]}, {δ, -1, 1,0.01}];
```

Interpolate, derivate, plot:

```
f = Interpolation[list];
df = D[f[x], x];
Plot[df, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Where `df` closely approximates `D[solution[δ, 1], δ]`.
As expected, the derivative is negative for $\delta <0$, and follows the form one might expect from the original plot.